# undefined reference to ctor and dctor simple code

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, ld

This simple piece of code really gives me hard time, so could anyone be some kind and explain me what could possibly be wrong? I've got simple cpp file that uses class included from header file.

lib.h

```
namespace tnamespace {    
class base{                                        
    virtual ~base() {};                            
};                                                 
class test/*: public base*/ {                                                                     
    public:                                                                                       

    test();                                                                                       
    test();                                                                                      
};                                                                                                
}
```

lib.cxx

```
#include "lib.h"

namespace tnamespace{                                                                                             
    test::test() {};
    test::~test() {}
}
```

start.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <lib.h>

int main() {
    tnamespace::test d;
    return 0;
}
```

i use gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 and compile project with

```
g++ start.cpp -I./ext_lib -Wall
```

got following linker error

/tmp/ccK2v6GD.o: In function `main':

start.cpp:(.text+0x7a): undefined reference to `tnamespace::test::test()'

start.cpp:(.text+0x88): undefined reference to `tnamespace::test::~test()'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

i managed to find solution. I forgot to compile my lib. Proper g++ command

g++ start.cpp ext_lib/lib.cxx -I./ext_lib -Wall

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix/12574400#12574400

Comment: Need lib.cxx on command line `g++ start.cpp lib.cxx -I./ext_lib -Wall` or some library...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't compile `lib.cxx`, so the symbols aren't exported.

```
g++ start.cpp lib.cxx -I./ext_lib -Wall
```